# The meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the precise meaning of the sentence below? What remained in the atmosphere? The asteroid? How can that cause CO2? I am looking for a clear explanation.

> Even after the skies cleared, the enormous amounts of CO2 released
> when the asteroid impacted the limestone layer in the earth’s crust
> remained in the atmosphere, causing a massive greenhouse effect that
> lasted for thousands of years.

Comment: An asteroid had collided with the Earth. This released enormous amounts of CO2, which remained in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Even after the skies cleared, **the enormous amounts of CO2** <sup>*(released when the asteroid impacted the limestone layer in the earth’s crust)*</sup> remained in the atmosphere, causing a massive greenhouse effect that lasted for thousands of years.